# I can't find Windows after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Windows 7 laptop and now when I boot up it goes straight to Ubuntu with no option to choose Windows. How do I find Windows again?

Comment: You Meant 14.04 as there's no 14.01 Version and make sure you didn't Tick "Replace Ubuntu with Windows" rather than "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" During Installation.

Answer (score 2):

if yo installed ubuntu beside windows you need to install `boot-repair`

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

but if you are deleted windows and installed ubuntu this cannot help

Comment: +1. I have the same problem. I couldn't find Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 17. This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Check the partitions by mounting them into the system and if this doesn’t work get windows CD and just perform the loading and repairing..... also you can get back previous windows and files only if you didn't installed ubuntu by replacing windows 7 (this formats windows partition and installs ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try your keyboard shortcut that leads you to your boot options (`Boot Manager` menu, for me it's F9) within the first 5 seconds of the turning on of your computer. You might find Ubuntu enlisted there. If not, installing Boot Repair will most probably help.